# Facebook Page Plugin doesn't work if not on a web server

Tags: facebook

I am trying to incorporate the Facebook page plugin in my web site.  To test the syntax, I created a html file on my machine and added the code Facebook creates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script id="facebook-jssdk" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.4"></script>
<div>
    <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-width="400" data-height="600" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I opened the file in my browser, but it did not work.  I copied the file to a web server and opened it from there and Facebook displays.  What is the difference?